# Who owns values passed as pointers to Windows API functions?

Tags: c++, winapi

At the moment I am looking at the `fileBasicInfo` parameter of the [`PrjFillDirEntryBuffer()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/projectedfslib/nf-projectedfslib-prjfilldirentrybuffer) function. It is a pointer to a struct. Once I create a struct and pass it into the function, who is responsible for freeing the memory for the struct? I'm guessing that it's the caller since I don't think that function would save a reference to the struct anywhere, but I don't know how to tell for sure. Is there a rule? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Recommendation: Most of the time you can automatically allocate the structure and let the structure go out of scope when you're done with it.

Comment: Look at the docs. Very few functions allocate, transport, or free resources, and they all explicitly say so.

Comment: In general, by default, pointers you pass to API functions (everywhere, not only in Windows API) are considered to be owned by you and you are supposes to be in charge of managing those objects. When API starts owning them, this is usually specifically mentioned in the API documentation.

Comment: Rule of dumb: the one which creates the resource should release it.

Comment: @9072997 It is pre-allocated, not pre-filled. There would be no need to call a filling function to fill it in if it were already filled..

Comment: @SergeyA post that as an answer and I'd accept it

Comment: Or more generally, for these types of functions, you create an instance of the struct on the stack, initialize its members, pass it to the Win32 API via pointer, and then there's nothing left to do.  No explicit deallocation needed.

Comment: Hi, please feel free to mark the answer that help to you.Or write your own answers which available for you, and mark it to highlight.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT SergeyA's comment was what really cleared this up for me. I don't know of a way to mark a comment as an answer to a question. I could copy and paste it as my own answer, but that seems like I am trying to steal reputation.

Comment: @SergeyA Could you please convert that comments as an answer, since it did solve OP's issue?

Answer (score 4):

The function simply fills the `PRJ_FILE_BASIC_INFO` struct that you provide to it.  It has no way of knowing how the struct was allocated, so it cannot free the struct for you.  So you are responsible for allocating the struct before calling the function, and for freeing the struct when you no longer need it.  How you chose to allocate/free it is up to you.